# Add up INT values for each day in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have this table in my database:

[image]

Each `time` is a UNIX timestamp that range from December 6 to December 14(today). Some rows have the same day but not the same time (ie: Dec 14 8:39PM, Dec 14 10:21 PM) and such.

However, I'm trying to make a mysql query that will add up all `gained` points for each day.

I currently have a `while` list that goes down the list sorted by `uid` because `UID` is the `id` of the user.

This is my currently `while` query:

```
$get_statuses = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `history` 
                             WHERE `uid` = '$logged[id]' 
                             ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 50");
```

Assuming I use this `$fullDate = date("F j, Y", $status['4']);` for each current loop beacuse I did this `while ($status = mysql_fetch_array($get_statuses)) {...}`, how do I do this?

Maybe a `SELECT(SUM)`?

Comment: Try to avoid the use of `mysql_*`. Those functions are deprecated now and bring some serious security implications with them...

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: See the huge red warnings in the API docs > http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Oh thanks... that's annoying. Ugh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query.

```
SELECT Date(From_unixtime(`time`)) AS `Date`, 
       Sum(`gained`) 
FROM   `tbl` 
WHERE `uid` = '$logged_id'
GROUP  BY `Date` 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

You can add More where condition here. Like

```
From_unixtime(`time`) >= '2012-12-06' 
AND
From_unixtime(`time`) <= '2012-12-14'
```

Comment: Well obviously it will be longer since the table will keep adding rows... but  on your query... how would I use it... I don't recognize a table header being `date`

Comment: `date` is the column alias for `Date(From_unixtime(\`time\`))` And column aliases can be used with `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `HAVING`